UdpClient C# Отправка пакетов по определенному протоколу
У меня возникла проблема с кодированием пакетов по определенному протоколу. Мне нужно отправить массив байтов. Но проблема в том, что этот пакет должен иметь определенную структуру. Структура заголовка на картинке:

Обратите внимание на длину элемента "Резерв" (6 бит). Как мне закодировать такой заголовок, используя массив байтов (byte[])?

Для всей структуры достаточно массива из 8 байтов: байты 0,1 - длина, байт 2 - версия и т.д.  Последние три элемента кодируются одним байтом, в котором ненулевые значения будут только в двух последних битах для элементов R 0x02 и С 0x01.

Возмите перечисление
[Flags]
public enum HeaderFlags : byte
{
    R = 2,
    C = 1,
    None = 0
}

Заголовок может выглядеть примерно так
public struct Header
{
    public ushort Length;
    public byte Version;
    public byte TTL;
    public ushort SN;
    public byte Type;
    public HeaderFlags Options;
}

Header header = new();
header.Options = HeaderFlags.R | HeaderFlags.C;

Сериализация может выглядеть так
byte[] headerBytes = new byte[8];
BinaryPrimitives.WriteUInt16LittleEndian(headerBytes, header.Length);
headerBytes[2] = header.Version;
headerBytes[3] = header.TTL;
BinaryPrimitives.WriteUInt16LittleEndian(headerBytes.AsSpan()[4..], header.SN);
headerBytes[6] = header.Type;
headerBytes[7] = (byte)header.Options;


Благодарю за помощь
